# Choose Jenkins-Slave based on axis

Tags: docker, jenkins

I've a multi configuration project in Jenkins with 2 axis (I can't post an image because of new account/low reputation):

- PHP72
- PHP74

So, there's a PHP72 and PHP74 axis. Let's call it the "target" axis... Now, I've 2 Jenkins Slaves that are running in Docker containers. The first slave (Slave A) provides PHP 7.2.x environment while the other slave (Slave B) provides PHP 7.4.x...

**How can I tell Jenkins that it should use Slave A for axis PHP72 and Slave B for PHP74 axis?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for reference... I finally got it to work using combination filter. At first I assigned a label to my slaves and two axis to my job:

1. slave-axis
2. label-axis (called version)

In the slave axis I selected the labels of the slaves that should execute the job. The label/version axis contains PHP72 and PHP74. Afterwards, I enabled the combination filter and configured as follows:

```
(slave=="SlaveA" && version=="PHP72") || (slave=="SlaveB" && version=="PHP74")
```